# javascript: convert BASE64 to BLOB fails in safari only

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

I'm trying to convert a blob (created with [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/)) to a base64 and persist it in the websql database. Then I would also like to do this process the other way around. Anyway, my test code (without the compression) looks something like:

```
var blob = new Blob([data], {
    type : "text/plain"
});

blobToBase64(blob, function(b64) {      // convert BLOB to BASE64
    var newBlob = base64ToBlob(b64) ;   // convert BASE64 to BLOB
    console.log(blob.size + " != " + newBlob.size) ;
});
```

see a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/4bn5G/

So, the strange thing is, that it works in Chrome, but not in Safari (als not on my iPad).

I also tried to rewrite the base64ToBlob to

```
function base64ToBlob(base64) {
    var binary = atob(base64);
    return new Blob([binary]) ;
}
```

But then de uncompress doesn't work anymore, giving me an "IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1 " exception

Any suggestion what might be wrong in my code ?

Thnx

Comment: Yeah..  I have the same issue.  bas64 -> blob conversion fails in safari but works in IE, Chrome and Firefox.  Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found a solution just after posting my comment.

Instead of

`new Blob([data]);`

do

`new Blob([data.buffer]);`

notice the addition of ".buffer"

Comment: That would be great! I don't see however where to apply this. Could you modify my jsfiddle ?