# export csv is not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

code written in javascript to download the data in CSV. which is working fine in FF, Chrome browser. But in Safari showing Type Error 
"TypeError: '[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' })')"

I tried in all forum to solve this issue. but nothing work out.

Code  I followed :

```
const blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
  navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
} else {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
      // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.setAttribute('href', url);
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.style = 'visibility:hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
}
```

Suggestions and solutions welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript: convert BASE64 to BLOB fails in safari only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924501/javascript-convert-base64-to-blob-fails-in-safari-only)